# Mysql missing rows on Select new or updated rows

Tags: mysql

I have a partitioned table with an updatedatetime field with default = current_timestamp(3).
I've given a simplified table definition below:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `updatedatetime` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`updatedatetime`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`updatedatetime`))
(PARTITION p00 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P00178 VALUES LESS THAN (738930) ENGINE = InnoDB
...
```

I then have multiple asynchronous processes which insert and update rows in this table. I ensure that the updatedatetime is always set to default (current_timestamp(3)) in both of these cases. These are never run in an explicit transaction. My isolation level is set to 'READ COMMITTED'.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (id, default);
```

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET updatedatetime = default
WHERE ID = @id;
```

In a service, I need to constantly monitor for new or updated rows using a version of the following:

```
DateTime sinceDateTime = DateTime.Now;

while(true) {

  string sql = $@"
      SELECT
        *
      FROM mytable
      WHERE updatedatetime >= @sinceDatetime
      ORDER BY updatedatetime ASC;";

  using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(...))
  {
      var results = await conn.QueryAsync(sql, new
      {
          sinceDateTime,
      });

      if(results.Any()) {
          Console.WriteLine($"SinceDateTime: {sinceDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}");
      
          sinceDateTime = results.Max(r => r.UpdateDateTime);

          Console.WriteLine($"MaxUpdateDateTime: {sinceDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}");

          Console.WriteLine($"Ids:\n  {string.Join("  \n", results.Select(r => r.Id))}");
      }
  }
  await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Very very occassionally, an iteration of the above loop is missing rows. For example,

```
SinceDateTime:     2023-09-06 09:51:13.014
MaxUpdateDateTime: 2023-09-06 09:51:13.109
Ids:
  163127158
  163127159
  163127160
  163127161
  163127162
  163127163
  163127164
  163127165
  163127166
  163127168
```

But if I query the database, I can see that id 163127167 exists with an updatedatetime between the SinceDateTime and the MaxUpdateDateTime.

[image]

Any ideas on how I might be skipping rows?

[Edit]: I think the problem may be that current_timestamp is calculated at the beginning of the transaction. I think MySQL implicitly wraps all statements in a transaction, and for some reason, very occassionally, an insert or update is taking longer to complete than another insert or update that started after it.

Comment: The timestamp only changes when the commit was executed, when you get. Your data all 100 ms this mustn't be the case

Comment: *I ensure that the updatedatetime is always set to default (current_timestamp(3)) in both of these cases.* ??? Define this column with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)` in the table structure and do not set it in the queries at all. The server will assign specified value while creating a row unconditionally and w/o alternatives. If INSERT does not fail then you may be sure that the value is assigned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the datetime field with a precision of 3 milliseconds is fairly granular, but in a high-concurrency environment, it's possible for multiple operations to occur within the same millisecond. When you're detecting changes based on this field, you could miss rows!! This is because if two records have the exact same timestamp and you only pick one of them as the "MaxUpdateDateTime", then on the next loop, you might miss the other record(s) with the same timestamp.
So, if it is possible, increase the precision of the updatedatetime field. This might help, but it's not guaranteed, especially in extremely high-concurrency scenarios.

- You said in a service you have:
  DateTime sinceDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  Are you sure about this application system clock and your DB server Clock not to have discrepancies?

Second, instead of relying only on the updatedatetime, consider implementing another mechanism to track changes. This could be as simple as a "change ID" field that auto-increments every time a row is inserted or updated. You can then track changes based on this ID, which is guaranteed to be unique and sequential.

**Note**: If there's any rounding happening due to the datetime precision, it could result in small discrepancies. So again if possible better to use an auto-increment ID.

Comment: Thanks Shila. Yes it is possible that multiple rows could have the same updatedatetime. This is why I've used ">= @sinceDateTime". Also you can see from the example that it's missed a row at 100ms but picked up the row at 109ms. 
There will be a discrepancy between DateTime.Now() and the DB datetime, but this will only be an issue on the first few iterations of the loop. I'm seeing this issue happen randomly over time.

Comment: With regard to the 'change ID' - this is a highly concurrent environment, how would I make sure that the ID is unique? Secondly, the table is partitioned on updatedatetime, so I must include this in my query to prevent querying across multiple partitions.

Comment: @MatthewConradie, if you consider it Autoincrement the Db takes care of the value, plus you should consider it as primary key of the table or at least a unique key.

Comment: @MatthewConradie I see you already have this field: `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, you just need to consider it as a unique key: ALTER TABLE your-table-name 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_ID UNIQUE(id); UQ_ID is just an alias you can change it

Comment: the auto_increment ID could work if I was only performing INSERTs, but I'm also doing UPDATEs and the auto_increment ID doesn't change on update.

Comment: @MatthewConradie, of course on update, id should not get changed, maybe you need to use insert instead of update query, but you do insert ON DUPLICATE KEY Update. Look at this link https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/; However I would suggest not to round in 3 digits that would be too short and not fault tolerant, in your emvironment